# Objective of maximal margin classifier with quadratic decision boundary

Tags: svm, kernel-trick

What is the objective for minimization for a maximal margin classifier with quadratic decision boundary of the form $ x^{T}Ax + b^Tx + c =0 $?

Comment: This question is so cryptic that it's hard to see how it could be answered.  Would you please provide some context and clarify what you mean by "objective"?  Would that be an *objective function* in an optimization problem or would it mean a *goal or purpose?*

Comment: the 'objective' is just the counterpart of $||W||_2$ in the case of linear maximal margin classifier.